# Unable to update value of particular element if it is empty in xml using NSIS installer

Tags: installation, nsis

I am working on NSIS [Nullsoft Installer System] Installer script. I am facing issue to update XML element value [used XML plugin] when element is empty for example,

```
**Element value to be updated: <Name />
After executing the below script, the output is : <Test />**

${xml::LoadFile} "$EXEDIR\install1.config" $0
${If} $0 != -1
  ${xml::GotoPath} "/InstallerInputs/Name" $0
  ${xml::FirstChild} "" $0 $1
  ${xml::SetNodeValue} "Test"
  ${xml::SaveFile} "$EXEDIR\install1.config" $0
  ${xml::Unload}
  ${EndIf}
```

XML structure is like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<InstallerInputs xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   **<Name></Name>** or **<Name />**
   <Password></Password>
</InstallerInputs>
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<InstallerInputs xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   **<Test/>**
   <Password></Password>
</InstallerInputs>
```

Any help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. After GotoPath you are already at the correct node, `${xml::FirstChild}` will fail because Name has no children.
2. `${xml::SetNodeValue}` seems to set the tag name, not the inner text.

Try this

```
!if 0
FileOpen $0 "$Temp\test.xml" w
FileWrite $0 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 '<InstallerInputs xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 '<Name></Name>$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 '<Password></Password>$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 '</InstallerInputs>$\r$\n'
FileClose $0
!endif

${xml::LoadFile} "$Temp\test.xml" $0
${If} $0 != -1
    ${xml::GotoPath} "/InstallerInputs/Name" $0
    ${If} $0 = 0
        ${xml::SetText}  "Test" $0
        ${xml::SaveFile} "$Temp\test.xml" $0
    ${EndIf}
    ${xml::Unload}
${EndIf}
```

Comment: ${xml::GotoPath} "/InstallerInputs/Name" $0                                           
${xml::FirstChild} "" $0 $1 --> If empty value in FirstChild method, it will return the first founded (i.e) Name element.                                                            
SetNodeValue -> sets the value of the current node. Actually element value gest updated when <Name>tes</Name> element is not empty. Anyway thanks for pointing to use SetText method. Its works now